# How to find second highest salary in mysql without using subquery, limit and top clause

Tags: mysql

How to fetch the highest second salary without sub query in MySQL

```
SELECT sal FROM jos_salary ORDER BY sal DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the DDL for the table

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `LIMIT`?

Comment: this quation asked in interview without using sub query to fetch second highest salary

Comment: id, salary , table field and values 1=500,2=500,3=400,

Answer (score 3):

The solution for this promlem is easily done using a **groupwise maximum** method by joining the table to itself based on the higher number for each row. Using this method, you can retrieve any highest position you like, depends on the number of joins or counting the number of rows in a single join. Depends on what method you like the most (IMO the second one with counting is more elegant).

Here is a solution for your problem using the groupwise method:

```
SELECT s1.sal
FROM job_salary s1
LEFT JOIN job_salary s2 ON s1.sal < s2.sal
LEFT JOIN job_salary s3 ON s2.sal < s3.sal
GROUP BY s1.sal
HAVING MAX(s3.sal) IS NULL AND MAX(s2.sal) IS NOT NULL
```

Or counting the number of the join matches:

```
SELECT s1.sal
FROM job_salary s1
LEFT JOIN job_salary s2 ON s1.sal < s2.sal
GROUP BY s1.sal
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s2.sal) = 1
```

By the way, if you do:

```
SELECT s1.sal, COUNT(DISTINCT s2.sal) AS sals_higher
FROM job_salary s1
LEFT JOIN job_salary s2 ON s1.sal < s2.sal
GROUP BY s1.sal
ORDER BY s1.sal DESC
```

You can see that the result ordered from highest to lowest salary, along with a sequence number, indicates the number of join rows from `s2` for each row in `s1`. When you join a table to itself on condition `s1.sal < s2.sal`, for each row it joins the number of salaries from `s2` that higher than the current salary in `s1`.
For example, on the highest salary, there is no higher salary than that because it's the highest one, that's why you got `0`, and on the second highest salary, we have only one salary higher, which is the highest one, that's why we got `1` and so on.
Here's how the result looks like:

```
+------+-------------+
| sal  | sals_higher |
+------+-------------+
| 7100 | 0           |
| 7000 | 1           |
| 6900 | 2           |
| 5400 | 3           |
| 5000 | 4           |
| 4700 | 5           |
+------+-------------+
```

Now, all you have to do is provide a suited condition in `HAVING` clause, which in your case equals `1`.

Good luck with the interview! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will work To find the **nth maximum number**(auto increment)

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 * from (SELECT TOP  nth_largest_no * FROM Products Order by sal desc) ORDER BY sal asc;
```

For Fifth Largest salery

```
SELECT 
  TOP 1 sal  from (SELECT TOP  5 sal FROM sal Order by price desc) ORDER BY sal asc;
```